# Modifying CSV file and Preserving Order

Tags: perl, csv

The question that follows is a made up simplified example of a more complex problem that I'm trying to solve. I would like to preserve the structure of the code, especially the use of the `%hash` to store the outcomes for each patient but I do not need to read the data file into memory (but I cannot find a way of reading my csv data file line by line from the end.)

My sample data is made up of events that occur to patients. A patient can be added to the study (Event=B) or he can die (Event=D) or exit the study(Event=F.) Death and Exit are the only two possible outcomes for each patient.

For each event I have the date of occurrence (in hours from given point in time), the unique ID number of each patient, the event and the Outcome (a field set to 0 for every patient.)

I'm trying to write a code that will change the input file by putting next to each addition of a new patient, what is his eventual outcome (death or exit.)

In order to do so, I read the file from the end, and whenever I encounter a death or exit of a patient, I populate a hash that matches patient ID with outcome. When I encounter an event telling me that a new patient has been added to the study, I then match his ID with those in the hash and change the value of "Outcome" from 0 to either D or F.

I have been able to write a code that reads the file from bottom and then creates a new modified file with the updated value for Outcome. The problem is that since I read the input file from bottom to top and print each line after reading it, the output file is in reversed order and I do not know how to change this. Also, ideally I don't want to create a new file bu I would like to simply modify the input one. However, I have failed with every attempt to do so.

Sample data:

```
Data,PatientNumber,Event,Outcome
25201027,562962838335407,B,0
25201028,562962838335408,B,0
25201100,562962838335407,D,0
25201128,562962838335408,F,0
```

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;

open (my $fh_input, "<", "mini_test2.csv")
  or die "cannot open > mini_test2.csv: $!";
my @lines = <$fh_input>;
close $fh_input;

open (my $fh_output, ">>", "Revised_mini_test2.csv")
  or die "cannot open > Revised_mini_test2.csv: $!";

my $length = scalar(@lines);
my %outcome;

my @input_variables;

for (my $i = 1; $i < @lines; $i++){
    chomp($lines[$length-$i]);
    @input_variables=split(/,/, $lines[$length - $i]);

    if ($input_variables[2] eq "D" || $input_variables[2] eq "F"){
        $outcome{$input_variables[1]} = $input_variables[2];
        my $line = join(",", @input_variables);
        print $fh_output $line . "\n";
    }
    elsif($input_variables[2] eq "B") {
         $input_variables[3]=$outcome{$input_variables[1]};
         my $line = join(",", @input_variables);
         print $fh_output $line . "\n";
    }
    else{
        # necessary since the actual data has many more possible "Events"
        my $line = join(",", @input_variables);
        print $fh_output $line . "\n";
    }
}
close $fh_output;
```

EDIT: desired output should be

```
Data,PatientNumber,Event,Outcome
25201027,562962838335407,B,D
25201028,562962838335408,B,F
25201100,562962838335407,D,0
25201128,562962838335408,F,0
```

Also, an additional complication is that the unique patient ID after the exit of a patient gets re-used. This means that I cannot do a 1st pass and store the outcome for each patient and a 2nd one to update the values of Outcome.

EDIT 2: let me clarify that when I say that each patient has a "unique ID" I mean that there cannot be in the study, at the same time, two patients with the same ID. However, if a patient exits the study, his ID gets re-used.

Comment: It looks like your output is just sorted based on the first field, is that the case?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot yes it is.

Comment: I'm wondering *why* this system was designed to re-use patient numbers. There are plenty of numbers in the world to go round, and re-using them is a false economy that has no advantage while making the programming process much more difficult

Comment: @g_puffo: I think you should write a proper example that demonstrates the behaviour of your data properly

Comment: @Borodin I definitely agree with you. Unfortunately, that is my case and I have no control over the data. I'm not sure what are you asking me to do: can you clarify?

Comment: @g_puffo: You have explained that patient numbers can be reassigned but that doesn't happen in your input data. Your sample should really be a thorough test case that includes, for instance, any possible data errors that you want to handle, or patients that are still  in a study that don't have an exit record. Only you know your requirements and you shouldn't make us guess them

Comment: @Borodin It's a simplified version of a problem I'm dealing with. It's not my homework: luckily, I'm past that stage in life. Unfortunately, I cannot share the actual data (in any form) so I had to come up with this in order to consult with you guys. I will be editing my question so to address your concerns.

Comment: @g_puffo: It's never too late to learn. Ergo it's never too late for homework! Have you seen the update to my solution? I think it will do what you need

Comment: @Borodin I'm looking at it right now: thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update

I have just read your additional information that patient numbers are re-used once they exit the study. Why you would design a system like that I don't know, but there it is

It becomes far harder to write something straightforward without reading the file into an array, so that's what I have done here

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use autodie;

open my $fh, '<', 'mini_test2.csv';
my @data;
while ( <$fh> ) {
    chomp;
    push @data, [ split /,/ ];
}

my %outcome;

for ( my $i = $#data; $i > 0; --$i ) {
    my ($patient_number, $event) = @{$data[$i]}[1,2];
    if ( $event =~ /[DF]/ ) {
        $outcome{$patient_number} = $event;
    }
    elsif ( $event =~ /[B]/ ) {
        $data[$i][3] = delete $outcome{$patient_number} // 0;
    }
}

print join(',', @$_), "\n" for @data;
```

**output**

```
Data,PatientNumber,Event,Outcome
25201027,562962838335407,B,D
25201028,562962838335408,B,F
25201100,562962838335407,D,0
25201128,562962838335408,F,0
```

---

There are a few ways to approach this. I have chosen to take two passes through the file, first accumulating the outcome for each patient in a hash, and then replacing all the outcome fields in the `B` records

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use autodie;

use Fcntl ':seek';

my %outcome;

open my $fh, '<', 'mini_test2.csv';
<$fh>; # Drop header

while ( <$fh> ) {
  chomp;
  my @fields = split /,/;
  my ($patient_number, $event) = @fields[1,2];
  if ( $event =~ /[DF]/ ) {
    $outcome{$patient_number} = $event;
  }
}

seek $fh, 0, SEEK_SET; # Rewind

print scalar <$fh>; # Copy header

while ( <$fh> ) {
  chomp;
  my @fields = split /,/;
  my ($patient_number, $event) = @fields[1,2];
  if ( $event !~ /[DF]/ ) {
    $fields[3] = $outcome{$patient_number} // 0;
  }
  print join(',', @fields), "\n";
}
```

**output**

```
Data,PatientNumber,Event,Outcome
25201027,562962838335407,B,D
25201028,562962838335408,B,F
25201100,562962838335407,D,0
25201128,562962838335408,F,0
```

Comment: But, how does your code address the issue of re-used IDs?

Comment: @g_puffo: It didn't. I was busy coding a solution while that gem was revealed

Comment: Very interesting: I'll try implementing it into my actual code right away. Can you explain why do you prefer to use the notation `$event =~ /[B]/` rather than `$event eq "B"?` Also, does `--$i` mean that you start from last value and reduce it by 1 at each iteration?

Comment: @g_puffo: I have used `/[B]/` just for symmetry with `/[DF]/`, and yes, `--$i` decrements `$i` by one in the same way that `++$i` increments it

Answer (score -1):

What we can do is instead of printing out the line at each stage, we'll write it back to the array of lines.  Then we can just print them out at the end.

```
for (my $i=$#lines; i>=0; i--)
{
    chomp $lines[$i];
    @input_variables = split /,/, $lines[$i];
    if ($input_variables[2] eq "D" || $input_variables[2] eq "F")
    {
         $outcome{$input_variables[1]}=$input_variables[2];
    }else
    {
         $input_variables[3]=$outcome{$input_variables[1]};
    }
    $line[$i] = join ",", @input_variables;
}

$, = "\n";     #Make list seperator for printing a newline.

print $fh_output @lines;
```

As for the second question of modifying the original file.  It is possible to open a file for both reading and writing using modes "+<", "+>", or "+>>".  **Don't do this!**  It is error prone as you must replace data character by character.

The standard way to "modify" an existing file is to rename it, read from the renamed file, write to a new file with the original name, and delete the temp file.

```
my $file_name = "mini_test2.csv";
my $tmp_file_name = $file_name . ".tmp";
rename $file_name, $tmp_file_name;
open (my $fh_input, "<", $tmp_file_name)
    or die "cannot open > $tmp_file_name: $!";

open (my $fh_output, ">>", $file_name)
    or die "cannot open > $file_name: $!";

#Your code to process the data.

close $fh_input;
close $fh_output;

#delete the temp file
unlink $tmp_file_name;
```

But, in your case, you slurp all of the data into memory right away.  Just open for writing that clobbers existing files

```
open (my $fh_output, ">", "mini_test2.csv")
    or die "cannot open > mini_test2.csv: $!";
```

Comment: Sorry, I have just added an important piece of information: the unique patient ID gets re-used after the exit of a patient. Hence, I cannot do, as you suggest, a 1st pass to populate the hash.

Comment: @g_puffo It's not a unique ID if it gets reused, now is it? :)

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot it is for as long as the patient is in the study... but I do see your point: I should have been more clear about it :)